# Tikz inlcluded image will not move

Tags: latex, tikz

I have the following tikz image:

```latex
\def\step{1.2}
\def\angle{50}
% \pgfmathtruncatemacro[#1]{\xplusone}{#1+1}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
        \node[circle, draw] at ($ (\x*\step, 0)$) (\x) {$v_\x$};
    }

    \foreach  \x in {0,...,3}  {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\x+1} 
        \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}] 
            (\x) edge [-Latex, bend left=\angle]  node [] {$e_{1,1}$} (\j)
            (\x) edge [-Latex, bend right=\angle] node [below]  {$e_{1,1}$} (\j);
    }
    \node at (1,1)(ant) {\includegraphics[angle=-90, width=30pt]{acmart-master/figures/ant.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

No matter what I enter for `(a,b)` in `node at (a,b)(ant)..` The image of the ant will not move. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the pdf I am using: [ant.pdf](https://docdro.id/N9PTbS3)

Comment: It does work when I convert the image to png, but I would prefer to use pdfs. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to make a [mre] that does not rely on images we don't have access to? See if you can use `example-image` from the `mwe` package to recreate the problem

Comment: Thanks for adding a link to the pdf. If I guess enough packages and libraries get this code fragment to compile, the image moves just fine when changing the coordinates. Can you make a [mre] to make sure we talk about the same code?